# Magento2: When adding a category attribute programmatically should I use catalogSetupFactory or eavSetupFactory?

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav

It seems both following codes generates the same result, so when adding a category attribute programmatically should I use catalogSetupFactory or eavSetupFactory?

CategorySetupFactory:

```
<?php

namespace Unit4\Module9\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $catalogSetupFactory;


    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->catalogSetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }


    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

        /** @var CategorySetup $catalogSetup */
        $catalogSetup = $this->catalogSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $catalogSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Test Attribute',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

EavSetupFactory:

```
<?php

namespace Unit4\Module9\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Test Attribute',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adding one attribute it is irrelevant what you use.
The `CategorySetup` class extends `EavSetup` and the actual creation of the  attribute is done in the `EavSetup` class.

For consistency you should use the `categorySetup` since you are modifying the category instance.

The `CategorySetup` allows you in addition to the `EavSetup` to create categories.

Comment: What about adding >1 attribute?

Comment: you can do multiple calls to `addAttribute` in the same script

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have to use `$categorySetupFactory` to add new attribute programmatically at category level.

check below link.

https://github.com/belvg-public/Magento2_AdditionalImageTemplate/blob/master/BelVG/AdditionalImageTemplate/Setup/InstallData.php

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested both ways and they both works. Can you please elaborate why we need to use $categorySetupFactory ?

Comment: I am not sure about exact reason for it. For Magento 2.0 "eavSetupFactory" is used whereas for Magento 2.1 "categorySetupFactory" is used. I need more research on this to get exact answer.